# What are the conditions of an underwater environment?

Tags: movement, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, underwater, environmental-hazards

Parallel to [What are the conditions of a Zero-G environment?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/195187/what-are-the-conditions-of-a-zero-g-environment/195188#195188), Underwater environments are mentioned under Environmental Adaptation, but are otherwise undefined. Was this defined in an official book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Gamemaster's Guide* explains this on page 176.

> Land-based characters have some difficulties under water.
> The following applies whenever a character is swimming,
> walking in chest-deep water, or walking along the bottom.
>
> ### Close Attacks
>
> Close attacks underwater have a –2 circumstance penalty
> on attack checks. Characters with Movement (Environmental Adaptation (Aquatic)) ignore this penalty.
>
> ### Ranged Attacks
>
> Attacks with ranged weapons through water take a –2
> circumstance penalty on attack checks, in addition to the
> normal penalties for range.
>
> ### Attacks from Land
>
> Characters swimming, floating, or treading water on the
> surface, or wading in water at least chest deep, have
> partial cover from opponents on land. A completely submerged creature has total cover against opponents on
> land.
>
> ### Fire
>
> Effects with a fire descriptor are ineffective underwater.
> The surface of a body of water also blocks the effect of
> any such power.
>
> ### Invisibility
>
> A solid invisible body displaces water and leaves a visible,
> body-shaped “bubble” in the water. The invisible character
> still has partial concealment, but not total concealment.
>
> ### Perception and Stealth
>
> How far you can see underwater depends on the water’s clarity. As a guideline, creatures can see 60 feet (distance rank 1)
> if the water is clear, and half that (30 feet or distance rank 0)
> if it’s murky. Moving water is murky, unless it’s a particularly
> large, slow-moving river. It’s difficult to find cover or concealment to hide underwater (except along the bottom).